# Create new RMarkdown blocks for each item generated in a loop

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a dynamic number of very similar ggplot charts which I'm putting into a RMarkdown Beamer presentation.  I'd like each one to appear on its own page, but they're currently glued together on the same slide (which makes sense, it's the intended behaviour, but I'm still not sure how to fix it for my particular use case).  Here's an example:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: beamer_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
```

## Page

```{r}
for(cyls in sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))) {
  print(mtcars %>%
    filter(cyl == cyls) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
    geom_point()+
    labs(title = paste(cyls,"cylinders")))
}

```
````

Which comes out looking like this:

[image]

When I'm more after something like this:

[image]

What do I need to change to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `results='asis'` and inserting markdown syntax before and after each plot:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
for(cyls in sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))) {
    cat(paste0("## ", cyls, " cylinders\n\n"))
    p = mtcars %>%
        filter(cyl == cyls) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
        geom_point() +
        labs(title = paste(cyls,"cylinders"))
    print(p)

    cat("\n\n---------------------\n\n")
}
```
````